# Web game with Rails: attack behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is responsible to perform attacks against mobs (aka. monsters) and I want to know if the best way to place this behavior is in the Player's model.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :kind, dependent: :destroy

    def attack(mob, min_damage, max_damage)
        [Mob.find(mob).name, rand(min_damage..max_damage)]
    end
end
```

Thinking in the logic: *players attack monsters*.

Am I right to turning this idea into code through Player's model? Or should I create a specific model just to perform this kind of behaviors?

Comment: This smells like Controller, and not model stuff. Do you use that attack method in more than one controller?

Comment: Yes, Marco. Actually, every time that an entity needs to attack "something" else (mob attack player, player attack mob, etc) the "attack" method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think an `Move` model can be good for your game. With an action model, you can specify it is a magical or physical attack, you can apply modifiers in terms of residual damage, critical hits, etc.
Also, i believe the monster can attack the player too, so with a separate model, all you need to do is create and instance of it passing the parameters/modifiers you want.

Comment: May you exemplify me a well-designed structure whose will suit my problem? I mean, there is possible for you to transform your answer onto (simple) code for know/ledge/how proposals?